# Find all rows not matching a criteria, MySQLi MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Alright, I have never asked a question here before, but here goes.

In my PHP script I currently have a query that retrieves all threads matching user ID in the `threads_read` table (records all read thread ids, Unix timestamp, and user ID). Then, I use another query to retrieve all the matching rows in an `important_threads` table that contains thread id.

This may be a very simple question to answer but I'm not too familiar with MySQL(i), but how would I make a query that retrieves all NON matching rows in an `important_threads` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM threads_read WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM important_threads)
```

That is a little resource heavy, but it does the job.

I would really recommend against that type of a database structure, though. Simply marking a table called 'threads' that would have a column to see if it was read or important would be a much more fluent design.

Best of luck!

Comment: I have this query set up. `$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mybb_threadsread WHERE tid NOT IN (SELECT tid FROM mybb_threadfields_data)");`

However when I retrieve an array from the query with `$db->fetch_array($query)` it returns nothing. I `var_dump()`'ed the query, and it returned this: `object(mysqli_result)#14 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: Firstly, try using PDO, I used to use MySQLi and I can say from experience, PDO rocks. Secondly, are you sure you have items in your threadsread table that aren't in your threadfields_data table? Also, it is $query->fetch_array(), fetch_array doesn't have a param in OOP. :)

Comment: I'm using MyBB, and the $db class works for me :P I'll check out PDO for some of my independent projects. And there should be 2 results that are not read yet in the important table.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you try running that query on your database directly? Like in phpmyadmin? I don't know if there's a problem with the query or your PHP. Hard to troubleshoot from my perspective.

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0005 sec )

Comment: Looks like an issue with the query, could you try doing the subquery and make sure that return a result, "SELECT tid FROM mybb_threadfields_data"

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 1 ( 2 total, Query took 0.0005 sec)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12349/discussion-between-jonathan-and-dynamic)

Answer (score 2):

You could do a LEFT JOIN on the important_threads table and only get the rows where there are no matches in the table:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM 
    threads_read a
LEFT JOIN
    important_threads b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 
    a.user_id = 14 
    AND 
    b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: `a.id` would be the thread ID (I don't know what your field names are since you didn't give us your schema), and `b.id` would be the foreign key in the important_threads table which references the thread ID.

Comment: What would you replace with `tid` then? I'm not familiar with joins

Comment: What are the field names for your tables? Assuming the thread ID field name is the same on both tables (the thread ID), replace all occurrences of a.id and b.id with a.tid and b.tid respectively.

Comment: This worked as well as his, so upvote for you as well! Thank you!

Comment: Here, i would prefer this solution as the join happens over table level and subquery is avoided. so, +1.